# Generating Random Number of Circles in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, random

I'm trying to build a game using **javaFX**, just like **PACMAN**, but **not PACMAN**. I want generate some circles to generate (**5-10 circles**) randomly **when the game starts**. I know how to create circles but I **don't know how to** generate them randomly (I mean **random number of circles**, 5-10 circle).

please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Please include what you have tried

Comment: Some random generators return double x from range 0-1. So you have x * 5 to set random number from range 0-5. And then you can move the beginning of range adding 5 to your result, there you have a number from range 5 to 10.

x * 5 + 5

Comment: But this is not a javafx question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is as simple as easy as your question. Just use `Random` and some maths.
So just use this:

```
/**
* Numbers are included
*/
private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {
    Random r = new Random();

    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

If you don't understand `Numbers are included` then a simple explanation: if min = 5 and max = 10 then the result is something in between plus 5 and 10.

Please do your work because I found this answer in less than 1min.